# Getting the type of properties which belong to an XPO Object

Tags: c#, devexpress, xpo

Is there a way to get the type of a property of an XPO Object.
Example : my class is `User` with properties User_name and User_age.

I want to get the type of the User_name which is `string` in that case,
and User_age which is `int`.

How can I get this information with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each persistent class, XPO creates metadata, which you can use to access persistent members and their properties. The [Session.GetClassInfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoSession_GetClassInfotopic) method returns metadata (XPClassInfo) for a given type of object.

XPClassInfo provides the [FindMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoMetadataXPClassInfo_FindMembertopic) and [GetMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoMetadataXPClassInfo_GetMembertopic) methods to access persistent property definition by its name (XPMemberInfo).

XPMemberInfo provides the [MemberType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXpoMetadataXPMemberInfo_MemberTypetopic) property, which returns the actual type of a corresponding persistent property.